# Modifying the first item of the array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have to modify the first item of the array, however I failed, but I manage to do a code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">                        
    <?php if($results) {
        $x= 1;
        foreach ($results as $data)  { $x++; ?>
            <div class="item <?php if($x == 1) { echo 'active';} ?>">
                <img alt="" src="<?=base_url('uploads/'.$data->file)?>">
            </div>
        <?php }
    } ?>                        
</div>
```

Assuming that I will get these result:

```
<div class="item active">
    <img alt="" src="http://localhost/ideal_visa/uploads/fd5fa6cfbe64c8b68664ddbf0546d81b.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img alt="" src="http://localhost/ideal_visa/uploads/c43c064de5cb9e751c723eb9791f2107.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img alt="" src="http://localhost/ideal_visa/uploads/e3137475f6330d52e9cd9c6fc5efba1e.jpg">
</div>
```

I only have to add `active` on the first item of the array.

Comment: So what ? you have `active` only on the first item no ? What is the problem ?

Comment: initialize `$x` with `0`

Comment: `$x= 1;` + `$x++;` as first statement in your loop means that `if ($x == 1)` will _never_ be true

Comment: `$x = 0;` solved the problem. thanks @dikesh

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="carousel-inner">                        
    <?php if($results) {
        $x= 1;
        foreach ($results as $data)  { ?>
            <div class="item <?php if($x == 1) { echo 'active';} ?>">
                <img alt="" src="<?=base_url('uploads/'.$data->file)?>">
            </div>
        <?php  $x++; }
    } ?>                        
</div>
```

you need to increment the `x` value after the iteration

**OR**

```
<div class="carousel-inner">                        
        <?php if($results) {
            foreach ($results as $x=>$data)  { ?>
                <div class="item <?php if($x==0) echo 'active'; ?>">
                    <img alt="" src="<?=base_url('uploads/'.$data->file)?>">
                </div>
            <?php }
        } ?>                        
    </div>
```

you can just utilize associative key of the array `$data` and change the condition to `$x==0`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do extra `$x` for this.You can use `foreach` with `key => value` and check if it's first index

```
<?php if($results) {
    foreach ($results as $key=>$data)  { ?>
        <div class="item <?php echo ($key == 0)? 'active':''; ?>">
            <img alt="" src="<?=base_url('uploads/'.$data->file)?>">
        </div>
  <?php }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You have put `$x=1` before the `foreach`, then increment it *at the start*.

That means when you show the *first* image, `$x==2`.

---

### Solution

You can either start with `$x=0` **or** move the line `$x++` to the end of the loop:

```
    foreach ($results as $data)  { ?>
        <div class="item <?php if($x == 1) { echo 'active';} ?>">
            <img alt="" src="<?=base_url('uploads/'.$data->file)?>">
        </div>
    <?php $x++; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `$x` **after** the iteration

```
<?php 
if($results) {   
  $x= 1; 
  foreach ($results as $data)  {?>
  <div class="item <?php if($x == 1) { echo 'active';} ?>">
      <img alt="" src="<?=base_url('uploads/'.$data->file)?>">
  </div>
<?php 
  $x++;
  } 
} ?>
```